# Concatenate/Split Cells and Delete Unnecessary Rows in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation, vba

I have a large data set in which I need to concatenate multiple rows together and then delete the source rows.

[Example data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJWxj.jpg)

Current logic I wish to apply:

1. Look through data and find matching ID's in column A.
2. Concatenate the data from the matching ID's to form a single row.
3. Delete the (now) unnecessary rows.
4. Split the concatenated cell into multiple cells/columns.

Is this possible in excel using a formula or macro? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

edit: if possible, can someone please help me get started with the macro as well?

Comment: Yes it is possible with a 'VBA sub procedure but not with a formula.

Comment: *To the viewers of this 'question'* - Why doesn't someone create an answer that states *Yes, this is possible* then we can use it to mark all future *Is it posssible...* questions as duplicate?

Comment: @Jeeped - it would be trolling, I think...

Comment: @Jeeped using remove duplicates on a copy of the IDs, then: `=IFERROR(INDEX($B:$D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$A$7)/($A$2:$A$7=$A12),INT((COLUMN(A:A)-1)/3)+1),MOD(COLUMN(A:A)-1,3)+1),"")`

Comment: @computersareneat Stack Overflow is not a code for me site nor a show me where to start site.  Please show what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Yes, a 'helper' column could identify duplicates and aid filtering but I took the OP literally to mean that they wanted to delete rows with a formula. Nice formula btw.